# enumerating grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation

I have a pandas data frame where each row is a sub-sequence. I want to do the following;

1. Group the data by 'SN' then order each group by 'date'.
2. Create an additional column called 'steps' which is an enumeration of rows in each group from 0-to-n (0:n) based on this CONDITION: within each ordered group, start enumeration from 0 until 'event' equals 1, repeat this within each group. ALWAYS restart enumeration each time 'SN' changes. Please refer to code and example images for further clarity...Thanks in advance guys!

The code below creates the original data

```
data = {'date':['1/1/18', '1/2/18', '1/3/18', '1/1/18', '1/2/18', '2/2/18', 2/3/18', '2/4/18', '2/4/18', '2/4/18', '2/5/18'],
        'SN': ['111', '111', '111', '222', '222','222', '333', '333', '333', '444', '444'],
        'feat1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
        'event':[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]}

orig_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

orig_data:
[image]

The output desired is as follows:

[image]

Comment: So do you have a question?

Comment: Your desired output seems nothing but addition of two new columns `Event` and `step` based on the value of `event` and `timestep` respectively.

Comment: @jpp yes the question as implied in item #2 is to enumerate rows within each group with the condition that if event == 1 within each group, restart the enumeration.

Comment: @Curious_MInd well said, would be great if you could demo how I can produce the output following conditions in item #1. After grouping by 'id' then enumerate rows within each group but restarting the enumeration when 'event' ==1 within each group. If 'event' !=1 continue the enumeration only within a group.

Comment: @Curious_MInd - I edited the desired output, I accidentally repeated the 'event' column.

Comment: @EdM I think output steps are still incorrect. check pelase

Comment: @ YOLO where do you think the steps value/s aren't correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you might try this;

EDITED

```
orig_data['steps_'] = orig_data.groupby(['SN',(1 == orig_data['event'].shift(1)).cumsum()]).cumcount()

print(orig_data)

     SN    date  event  feat1  steps_
0   111  1/1/18      0      1       0
1   111  1/2/18      0      2       1
2   111  1/3/18      1      3       2
3   222  1/1/18      0      4       0
4   222  1/2/18      1      5       1
5   222  2/2/18      0      6       0
6   333  2/3/18      0      7       0
7   333  2/4/18      1      8       1
8   333  2/4/18      0      9       0
9   444  2/4/18      0     10       0
10  444  2/5/18      1     11       1
```

note; I've omitted the groupby on 'date', because ordering by 'date' gives problems with '333'. '2/4/18' is given twice, so which one comes first?

Comment: thanks! This partially works except it continues the count through different "id". Here's what I need - For every unique id, start the count and continue on 1 condition, that is, if 'event' equals 1 then stop the count and restart at 0 the next row. So every change of 'id' the count starts over...

Comment: I understand, but then your output example isn't right. Please provide a new output example

Comment: OK - fair enough, will do so shortly, looking forward to your assistance....thanks again Zanshin!

Comment: sorry for the delayed update. I have updated the data and code snippet. I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Comment: @EdM, is this what  you are looking for?

Comment: yes! I had modified it exactly as you have it here and works perfectly!! Thanks for your contribution!!